# Gathering data from huge text files

Tags: python

I have a text file composed of several subsequent tables. I need to get certain values from certain tables and save them in an output file. Every table has a header which contains a string that can be used to find specific tables. The size of these text files can vary from tenths of MB to some GB. I have written the following script to do the job:

```
string = 'str'
index = 20
n = 2

in_file = open('file.txt')
out_file = open("out.txt", 'w')
current_line = 0

for i in range(-index,index+1):
    for j in range(-index,index+1):
        for line in in_file:
            if string in line:
                En = line.split().pop(4)
                for line in in_file:
                    current_line += 1
                    if current_line == 2*(n+1)+2:
                        x = line.split().pop(10)
                    elif current_line == 3*(n+1)+2:
                        y = line.split().pop(10)
                    elif current_line == 4*(n+1)+2:
                        z = line.split().pop(10)
                        current_line = 0
                        break
                print i, j, En, x, y, z
                data = "%d %d %s %s %s %s\n" % (i,j,En,x,y,z)
                out_file.write(data)
                break
in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

The script reads the file line by line searching for the specified string ('str' in this example). When found, it then extracts a value from the line containing the string and continue reading the lines that form the data table itself. Since all the tables in the file have the same number of lines and columns, I've used the variable current_line to keep track of which line is read and to specify which line contains the data I need. The first two for-loops are just there to generate a pair of indexes that I need to be printed in the output file (in this case they are between -20 and 20).

The script works fine. But since I've been learning python by myself for about one month, and the files I have to handle can be very big, I'm asking for advices on how to make the script more efficient, and overall, better.

Also, since the tables are regular, I can know beforehand which are the lines that contain the values I need. So I was wondering, instead of reading all the lines in the file, is it possible to specify which lines have to be read and then jump directly between them?

[Sample input file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbqaa7mkyrfwk41/sample_input.txt?dl=0)

Here's a sample input file. I've included just some tables so you can have an idea how it's organized. This file is composed by two blocks with three tables each. In this sample file, the string "table   #" is what is used to find the data to be extracted.

[Sample output file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr25i0xzd8rf2mx/test2.txt?dl=0)

And here's a sample output file. Keep in mind that these two files are not equivalent! This output was created by my script using an input file containing 1681 blocks of 16 tables. Each table had 13 lines just as in the sample input file.

Comment: Your code makes no sense as you have exhausted the file iterator after the first loop, also unless you know the line numbers before you loop then there is no way to jump to the lines

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - The `break` short-circuits that loop when a table is found (4-line block at the bottom of the `if`) to generate the next index pair.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, consider [codereview.se]

Comment: @SnoProblem, I missed the last break, hard to make any sense of the code looking at it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Which loop are you talking about? "for i in range"? I haven't tried to do the arithmetics yet, but I'm almost sure I can determine the line numbers before the loop. Edit: Guess I got ninjed ;).

Comment: @Yeshua, a sample of your input and expected output would be a lot easier to understand, I was also referring to knowing exactly which line the string was in not the line numbers. You have to iterate over the lines if you don't know exactly where the line is or there is not a common increment after you find the first line where the string appears in all subsequent lines. You could almost certainly cut down you code to a few lines using itertools.islice but I don't follow the logic of your code so I cannot suggest an exact implementation

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I included links to sample input and output files. Hopefully they make it easier to understand how my code works. I can give additional explanations if needed.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham About the lines, as you can see from the sample inupt file, it's written in a very clear pattern, so using the numbers given in the second line, the position of pretty much any line can be determined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the advice.